How do I change the "Select Language" text in drop-down list of Google translate element to the desired text I want
I have written necessary snippets for Google translate element on my website and I intend to change the "Select Language" text on the drop-down list to "Language".  i.e, a desired text I need.
This is what I intend to change
I have tried this:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
            {
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                autoDisplay: 'true',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
            }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src=
"https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit">
</script>

<script>
$("#google_translate_element").on("click", function () {
  var languages = $("iframe").contents().find(".text").get();
  console.log(languages);
  for (i = 0; i < languages.length; ++i) {
    var languageElem = languages[i];
    var Lang = languageElem.textContent;
    console.log(Lang);
    var nativeLang = getNativeLang(Lang);
    if (!nativeLang) {
      nativeLang = Lang;
    }
    languageElem.textContent = nativeLang;
    console.log(nativeLang);
  }
});
function getNativeLang(Lang) {
  switch (Lang) {
    case "Select Language":
      return "Language";
  }
}
</script>

I will be very grateful for any assistance.

Can you please provide a proper [mre] for this issue? I can't tell what you are trying to do there with var languages = $("iframe").contents().find(".text").get();, what iframe are you trying to select there?

Well thank you @CBroe well I searched for similar problem online and I found this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66703337/21266127) so I copied a part of it and added to my snippet hoping it'll work. But nothing works

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66723283/1427878 looks much more promising, if you asked me ...

@CBroe it worked but only onclick. Please how do I make it default once page loads up. On the code it says onclick, how do I make it default on load

@CBroe Hello sir!

I'd try to put it into googleTranslateElementInit, after you created the new google.translate.TranslateElement

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Try something like this integration.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Translate Custom Text</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function googleTranslateElementInit() {
            new google.translate.TranslateElement(
                {
                    pageLanguage: 'en',
                    autoDisplay: 'true',
                    layout: 
google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
            }, 'google_translate_element');
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js? 
   cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    <style>
        #google_translate_element select {
            width: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>

    <script>
        function changeTranslatePlaceholder() {
            var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.goog-te-menu-frame');
            var selectElem = iframe.contentDocument.querySelector('.goog-te-combo');
            if (selectElem) {
                selectElem.children[0].textContent = 'Language';
            }
        }

        function waitForTranslateElement() {
            var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.goog-te-menu-frame');
            if (iframe) {
                iframe.onload = function() {
                    changeTranslatePlaceholder();
                };
            } else {
                setTimeout(waitForTranslateElement, 1000);
            }
        }

        waitForTranslateElement();
    </script>
</body>
</html>


It didn't work please!
